# Linear interpolation with variable grid

Tags: interpolation

Suppose we are given a set of points $(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,\cdots,n$ with $x_1<x_2\cdots<x_n$. The usual form of linear interpolation partitions $[x_1,x_n]$ into a grid of $k$ equally spaced points and then interpolates between each pair of grid points.Sometimes, we specify the grid points manually (i.e. not equally spaced). Note that we are using OLS distance for error.

I would like to know the technical term (and R package) for the following variant: the grid points are $learned$. In other words, we specify that we would like to use exactly $k$ lines, for a total of $k+1$ grid points (with first and last grid point equal to $x_1,x_n)$. The interpolation then optimizes over the location of grid points. While the OLS is easy to write down for this, it looks like there will be strange boundary effects as the grid points are moved across each $x_i$. Is there a nice solution to this problem, perhaps by smoothing the distance between $y_i$ and whatever line is below it?

Comment: Because your description isn't clear, could you confirm the following interpretation? Given the points and a chosen $k\ge 1$, you seek a set of $k+1$ "grid points" $Z=(z_j,w_j)$ with $x_1=z_0\lt z_1\lt\cdots\lt z_k=x_n$ that minimizes $$\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-f(x_i;Z))^2$$. The function $f$ is the linear interpolator in $Z$, $$f(x;Z)=\frac{(x-z_j)w_{j+1}+(z_{j+1}-x)w_j}{z_{j+1}-z_j}$$ where $j$ (between $0$ and $k-1$) is determined by $z_j\le x\le z_{j+1}$.

Comment: @whuber: precisely.

Comment: This could be considered a form of [tag:change-point] analysis, especially for very small $k$.  Others might also view it in the framework of (piecewise linear) splines (although that doesn't help much in terms of selecting the "knots" $z_i$ in an optimal way).